# debug=true in .svc file?

Tags: wcf

Our WCF svc files contain the following:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="Foo"
                Factory="Bar"
                Language="C#"
                Debug="true" %>
```

What does debug=true mean in this case? web.config has debug=false, but I don't know what this one means and can't find a reference on MSDN.

Comment: Similar questions and helpful answers here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479798/wcf-svc-debug-true-ignored-when-when-release-compiling][1]

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362603/wcf-servicehost-debug-true-but-web-config-compilation-false][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479798/wcf-svc-debug-true-ignored-when-when-release-compiling
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362603/wcf-servicehost-debug-true-but-web-config-compilation-false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967286.aspx:

> Debug
>
> Indicates whether the Windows
>   Communication Foundation (WCF) service
>   should be compiled with debug symbols.
>   true if the WCF service should be
>   compiled with debug symbols;
>   otherwise, false.

Without debug symbols, it'll be harder to debug the services.

Comment: Thanks. What would this mean if web.config has debug=false?

Answer (score 0):

My belief is that this will override what's in the web.config but only for this specific service. I may be wrong, though.