# WCF .SVC Debug="true" ignored when when release compiling?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

By default a .SVC file contains Debug="true", I was wondering if this is ignored if you compile for release or is it still compiled with debug symbols?

Ex.

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WebPages.Interfaces.example" CodeBehind="example.svc.cs" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Debug=true` attribute in `@ServiceHost` directive only apply, if you are writing your service as **inline** code in .svc file, or implementing service in "**App_Code**" folder. *(It won't apply if already compiled into assembly and placed it into \bin directory.)*

Answer (score 1):

### Publishing a WCF service on IIS 8

I had this problem and i found this as the solution.
This worked for me perfectly (IIS 8)

All the credits goes to **György Balássy**

WCF services don’t run on IIS 8 with the default conჁguration, because the webserver doesn’t know, how to handle
incoming requests targeting .svc Ⴡles. You can teach it in two steps:

1. Add a new MIME type:
   Extension: .svc
   MIME type: application/octet-stream
   [Add a new MIME type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiYki.png)
2. Add a new Managed HTTP Handler:
   Request path: *.svc
   Type: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler
   Name: svc-Integrated
   [Add a new Managed HTTP Handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LrkV.png)

That's it!