# WCF service does not start

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I'm really sorry for asking this question again. There have been similar posts but none of the solutions worked for me.

I created a new WCF service project in VisualStudio2010. It creates a IService1.cs, Service1.svc and Service1.svc.cs

So, when I try to debug/start the service, I get the following error. I'm running Win7 x64. And I'm using the integrated VisualStudio development-server (right click the project --> go to page "Web").

> The type 'Projector.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value
>   in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found.

Any idea how to fix that without running it in IIS?

Thanks in advance.

The Service1.svc contains only one line:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Projector.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %>
```

The Service1.svc.cs contains an auto-generated class:

```
namespace Projector
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
```

Here's the Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you get any compile errors?

Comment: can you post your configuration file section <system.serviceModel> ..</system.serviceModel> ?

Comment: @vendettamit I added the Web.config above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the svc is useless if you are not working with IIS. Outside of IIS, the so called self hosted approach, needs you to write a something like this, where HelloWorldWcfServiceMessage is your type implementing the service contract. Additionaly, don't forget to configure an endpoint for the server and to make sure you are allowed to open a service on the configured port. The following code you can use in windows service or in a console program (better for testing and debugging). Hope that helps and I got your question right.

```
...
this.serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWorldWcfServiceMessage));
this.serviceHost.Open();
...

public class HelloWorldWcfServiceMessage : IHelloWorldWcfServiceMessage
{

}

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://HelloWorldServiceNamespace", Name = "PublicHelloWorldWCFService")]
public interface IHelloWorldWcfServiceMessage
{
    [OperationContract]
    string HelloWorldMessage(string name);
}
```

Comment: I'm currently trying this solution. But I want to set an own uri (HTTP with port) in as the second argument in the contructor of ServiceHost but I get an exception that it contains an HTTP address already. How would you configure an EndPoint?

Comment: Fixed it. I had to change the App.config file and remove/fix the EndPoint there.

Comment: Good. The app.config is the correct place for this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion with the names.

In the SVC you wrote:
CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs"
But you say your file name is Service.svc.cs (without the 1).

Comment: No, sorry. That was just a spelling mistake when writing the question. The actual code is correct. I fixed my question above.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved this**

This is all about Publishing a WCF service on IIS 8

All the credits goes to György Balássy

WCF services don’t run on IIS 8 with the default conჁguration, because the webserver doesn’t know, how to handle incoming requests targeting .svc Ⴡles. You can teach it in two steps:

Please check the same answer here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45979587/3059688